# Browser URLs and HTTP requests

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, browser

I'm currently building a web portfolio that combines many smaller web apps that I've made in the past. At the route (/) you find a page with links to these other smaller web apps. For instance, there's a link to route (/board-game) which takes you to the small board-game web app I made in the past.

What I'm struggling with is this. The smaller web app board-game serves it's html, css, and javascript to routes that don't include the prefix route (/board-game). So when a board-game page makes a request for (/css/style.css) nothing is loaded because the content is actually at (/board-game/css/style.css).

My question is this. Is there a way to re-route these requests to the appropriate route? I would like to avoid rewriting any part of these smaller projects. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Also, this is my current nginx.conf file.

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  upstream portfolio {
    server portfolio-svc:8080;
  }

  upstream board-game {
    server board-game-svc:8080;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://portfolio/;
    }

    location /board-game {
      proxy_pass http://board-game/;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show your current nginx config?

Comment: @Paul checkout the question revision

Comment: @Paul I'm starting to think the only way I can solve this is to dynamically set the request route given the `document.location.pathname`. Because once the content is served, it's in the browser, and the code/requests don't know where they are unless you tell them. So rather than making requests to (/css/style.css) I need to make requests to (document.location.pathname + /css/style.css). What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rewrite the path as part of the location, for example:

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  upstream portfolio {
    server portfolio-svc:8080;
  }

  upstream board-game {
    server board-game-svc:8080;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;

    location = / {
      proxy_pass http://portfolio/;
    }

    location = /board-game {
      proxy_pass http://board-game/;
      rewrite ^(.*)board-game(.*)$ http://board-game/$2 permanent;
      sub_filter /css/ /board-game/css/
    }
  }
}
```

You might have to play with the matching a bit, but that's the general idea.

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm looking for. What's happening is that when the board-game mini app makes a request to (/css/style.css) it doesn't include (/board-game) in the request at all. What I want to happen is that when the board-game mini app makes a request to (/css/style.css) the request is actually made to (/board-game/css/style.css). But I can't assume a request to (/css/style.css) should be rewritten to (/board-game/css/style.css) because other mini apps may make a similar request to (/css/style.css); they're own expectation of (/css/style.css)

Comment: Ah, indeed. Check out by update where I added the sub_filter Directive.  You have to add the module to your nginx instance. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html

Comment: Thank you so much! I have a nginx book that I read through a little while ago and it didn't mention the sub_filter directive at all. Very helpful directive though!

Comment: Maybe you're willing to answer this question too. If one of my mini apps uses client side routing for it's pages there's no way for nginx to manipulate the routes, correct? For instance, client side routing from (/) to (/rules) in the mini app would ideally become (/chart) to (/chart/rules) in the portfolio app. But since it's client side routing it doesn't seem like nginx could control that. Maybe I'm wrong though. Still relatively new to nginx

Comment: I would try it and see. If the files are served through NGINX, it seems reasonable that it could modify them as they’re being served.